# Automatically select a radio button when selecting a drop down list item and vice versa

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 4 radio buttons and a drop down list with 4 items.
I want to select appropriate item from drop down list when I check a radio button
and when I choose an item from drop down list the appropriate radio buttons I want to be checked.
How to make that in C# in Windows Form?

I tried:

```
private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1.SelectedItem = "Option1"; 
}

private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int SelIndex = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
    switch (SelIndex)
    {
        case 0:
            radioButton1.Checked = true;
            break;
     ....
```

Comment: You do not say “what” is not working with the current code. From what I can tell, I will assume you may be getting stack overflow exception. You need to be careful that the code in the event does not do something that will cause that event to fire again. I am betting this will happen with your current code. In other words, when the check box is changed, the radio button is also changed, so when you change one, the other also gets changed and this may create an infinite loop by one event calling the other continuously. It is difficult to confirm this with the current code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I commented, I am confident you are having a re-entrant problem when setting the radio button when the combo box changes and setting the combo box when the radio button changes. To help, below is a test you can try out yourself. Create a new `winforms` project, drop three (3) `RadioButtons` on to the form along with a `ComboBox`. It may look something like below.

[image]

If you run this form, and we have NOT wired up any events, then obviously the combo box will be empty and the first radio button will be checked. Since the radio button are in the same control (the form) then ONLY one can be selected at a time. The framework will “uncheck” the currently selected radio button when another is selected. This is done for you by the .Net Framework.

Before we start, I want to suggest you get familiar with the “Debug” output statement. When using `winforms` and we want to output some values “during” execution, in some cases as this one, we can NOT really use something like a `TextBox` in the form to display this debugging info as it will not display until the form is redrawn. If we create an infinite loop situation, then the text box would never show what we need to see. This is why the Debug commands are helpful here as they WILL be displayed immediately during execution. Point being is that Debug statements are used below and I recommend you get familiar with them.

So, let’s take a closer look at what is going on with the current code. From the posted code, the combo boxes `SelectedIndexChanged` event and each radio buttons `CheckedChanged` event is wired up. It may look something like…

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Debug.WriteLine("ComboBox1 Selection Changed");
  int SelIndex = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
  switch (SelIndex) {
    case 0:
      radioButton1.Checked = true;
      break;
    case 1:
      radioButton2.Checked = true;
      break;
    case 2:
      radioButton3.Checked = true;
      break;
  }
}
```

Radio button events…

```
private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Debug.WriteLine("RB1 Check Changed");
  comboBox1.SelectedItem = "Option1";
}

private void radioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Debug.WriteLine("RB2 Check Changed");
  comboBox1.SelectedItem = "Option2";
}

private void radioButton3_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Debug.WriteLine("RB3 Check Changed");
  comboBox1.SelectedItem = "Option3";
}
```

As can be seen, this code is similar to what you have posted, with the addition of the debug statements. If you run this code, when loaded, the first `Option1` will be selected in the combo box and the first radio button will be checked. You can also see the debug statement output in VS’s “Output” window. We can see that the one radio button event was fired and the combo boxes selection changed event was also fired. This makes sense as this is done for you when the form is loaded.

[image]

If you select a different radio button, then is what you will see is that… the currently selected radio buttons checked changed event will fire (from check to unchecked), then the newly checked radio buttons checked changed event will fire (from unchecked to checked) and finally the combo box’s selected index event will fire.

This may appear to be correct, however it is not. So, lets dig a little deeper. For starters it should be noted that since TWO (2) radio buttons checked changed events were fired, then WHY didn’t the combo boxes selection change event fire twice? In both radio buttons the combo box is changed or it may appear that way.

So, lets trace this and verify “why” we see this output. So, the user loads the form, radio button 1 is checked and combo box is set to “Option1”. Then the user checks radio button 3, it can be seen from the debug that radio button 1s checked changed event is fired. In the radio buttons checked changed event it sets the combo boxes value to “Option1.” This should raise a red flag; we want it to be “Option3” however the code is setting it to “Option1.” THAT is why the combo boxes selection changed event did NOT fire because the selection has not changed yet. Its value is still “Option1.”

Continuing, we can see that next the radio button 3’s checked changed event is fired. Inside this event we output the debug info and then change the combo boxes values to “Option3.” NOW, since the combo boxes value DID change, THEN the combo boxes selection changed event fires. In that event we output the debug statement, then check which selection was made, in this case the code will drop down to set the radio button 3 checked state to checked.

Again, as with the combo box, you may be asking… “why didn’t the radio button s checked changed event fire again?” The reason for this is that it was just changed by the user and since it was changed to checked, then it did not change.

From a user perspective, this would appear to work, however, it should be clear that setting the combo box to a value it already has and checking the radio button that is already checked is just unnecessary. Granted this may be acceptable as the goal is met in relation to the radio buttons changing the combo box when they change. Since, there is a bigger problem with the combo box, we will come back to this and address these unnecessary steps.

Next is the combo box, and it is here that there is an unacceptable issue that will cause the code to crash. To test this, restart the application, where the combo box has “Option1” selected and radio button 1 is checked. Then change the combo box value from “Option1” to “Option3.” Below is what you will see…

[image]

This has created an infinite loop and will eventually crash. From the debug statements it clearly appears the code is going back and forth from the combo boxes selection changed event to the radio button 3 event then to the radio button 1 event and so on… an infinite loop where one event is calling the other.

Without going into a detailed walk through, when the user selects “Option3” when “Option1” was previously selected… what is happening is this…

1. The combo boxes selected index changed event is fired… It sets radio button3 to checked.
2. Radio button 1’s checked state is fired by the framework to uncheck it. The code then sets the combo boxes value to “Option1” (which is not what we want.)
3. The combo boxes selected index changed event is fired… It sets radio button1 to checked.
4. Radio button 3’s checked state is fired by the framework to uncheck it. The code then sets the combo boxes value to “Option3.”
5. The combo boxes selected index changed event is fired… It sets radio button3 to checked.
6. Step 5 looks just like step1 and this process continues forever.

This is a good example of making sure that the code in the event doesn’t inadvertently cause a re-entrant into the same event. The problem here is that when we change one of the radio buttons, we want to change the combo box, but we do not want the combo box to change the radio button since WE changed it. Also, when we change the combo box value, we want to change the radio button but we do NOT want the radio button to change the combo box value since WE changed it.

So, how do we get around this? I will assume there may be other ways to achieve this, however one solution is to “TURN OFF” those events as described above. In other words, when the combo box selection changed event fires, we want to TURN OFF the radio button event when we SET the radio button values. In addition, in each of the radio button events, we want to TURN OFF the combo box selected index changed event to prevent it firing when the code changes it value. This should not only solve the infinite loop issue but it will also solve the earlier issue where the code was setting the combo box and the radio buttons when they did not need changing.

An example of this is shown in the code below.

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Debug.WriteLine("ComboBox1 Selection Changed");
  radioButton1.CheckedChanged -= new EventHandler(radioButton1_CheckedChanged);
  radioButton2.CheckedChanged -= new EventHandler(radioButton2_CheckedChanged);
  radioButton3.CheckedChanged -= new EventHandler(radioButton3_CheckedChanged);
  int SelIndex = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
  switch (SelIndex) {
    case 0:
      radioButton1.Checked = true;
      break;
    case 1:
      radioButton2.Checked = true;
      break;
    case 2:
      radioButton3.Checked = true;
      break;
  }
  radioButton1.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(radioButton1_CheckedChanged);
  radioButton2.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(radioButton2_CheckedChanged);
  radioButton3.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(radioButton3_CheckedChanged);
}

private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Debug.WriteLine("RB1 Check Changed");
  comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged -= new EventHandler(comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);
  comboBox1.SelectedItem = "Option1";
  comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);
}

private void radioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Debug.WriteLine("RB2 Check Changed");
  comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged -= new EventHandler(comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);
  comboBox1.SelectedItem = "Option2";
  comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);
}

private void radioButton3_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Debug.WriteLine("RB3 Check Changed");
  comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged -= new EventHandler(comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);
  comboBox1.SelectedItem = "Option3";
  comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);
}
```

I hope this make sense and helps.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the answers.
I would especially like to thank JohnG for his extremely clear and detailed answer.
Man, you're a very good teacher!
Yes, that's exactly what happens. The program went into an infinite loop and then crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple answer.  Make all the RadioButtons fire the same event, then:

```
    private void radioButtonAll_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RadioButton rb = (RadioButton)sender;
        if (rb.Checked)
        {
            String number = rb.Name.Remove(0, "radioButton".Length);
            String option = "Option" + number;
            if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() != option)
            {
                comboBox1.SelectedItem = option;
            }
        }
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            String number = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString().Remove(0, "Option".Length);
            RadioButton rb = this.Controls.Find("radioButton" + number, true).FirstOrDefault() as RadioButton;
            if (rb!=null && !rb.Checked)
            {
                rb.Checked = true;
            }
        }
    }
```